# Permission denied with fortrabbit new app logging

Tags: fortrabbit

Having some issues getting logging work on new apps.

I have my public key in my account and am able to push to deploy. If I run:

```
ssh log@log.eu2.frbit.com tail app-name
```

Permission denied (publickey).

Also, is it possible to use external logging with new apps? Instructions seem require SSH access.
http://help.fortrabbit.com/external-services#toc-logging

Answer (score 2):

For the permision denied error: Best contact the fortrabbit support with the App name and the output of `ssh -vvv log@log.eu2.frbit.com tail app-name`.

As for using external logging: No SSH required for that. Asuming you are using [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) you can just use an alternate log handler, eg:

- If you want to use [Loggly](https://www.loggly.com/): the handler is laready [on board](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/LogglyHandler.php)
- For [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) you can find one [here](https://github.com/vube/monolog-splunk-formatter)
- [Papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/) explains how to do it [here](http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/configuring-centralized-logging-from-php-apps/)

Of course, there are lots of more .. If you your external log services requires a special port, again: just let the support now.